# JAVA Desktop Application & HTML with browser

Tags: java, javascript, html, desktop-application, chromium

I am working on Java Desktop Application.

Is there any way so that I can download Google Chrome's source code, embed Chrome's source code in my Application so that it will allow me to create UI for the application using HTML.

I want to create UI completely based on HTML which calls my Java classes in background. I believe this will allow me to create more beautiful applications for my users.

I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try JavaFX 2 WebView component. It's embedded browser based on WebKit.